# Removing NA variables from plots in r

Tags: r

I am using R to analyze a data set that includes questions about income and one of the possible answers was "choose not to answer".

I was able to subset the data so that I could omit the "choose not to answer" by setting it equal to NA.

How can I remove the NAs so that it does not show up in my plots?  Below is a copy of my data...

Below is a copy of my code.  I have omitted "NAs", which I would like to remove "N/A", "Don't know" and "Refused".  When I look at my new table (xA) I see them removed.  When I look at the plot I get from the code below, the labels are still there but just with a value of 0.   Note I had to use different variables for the purpose of this example.

```
`# set up data so no NAs`
`xA <- na.omit(x)`

`xtab17 <- table(xA$email,xA$education)`
`xtab18 <- as.data.frame.table(xtab17); xtab18`

`barplot(xtab17,`
    `ylim = c(0,600),`
    `legend = rownames(xtab17),`
    `main = "Still shows NAs"`
    `)`
```

[Plot image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlRPn.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Perhaps you can share your code so that someone can help you.  Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Run `df <- droplevels(df)` and then plot, see if that helps.

Comment: did you check to see if `levels(xA$email)` and `levels(xA$education)` contain `NA` as a category?  Also, inspect `xtab17 ` to see if this table contains `NA`.

Comment: Hi Everyone, It seems like everyone here is a little more advanced than I am and I was not able to get any of these to work.  However, I did the plot to eventually turn out.  I used "na.rm=T" in my logic and I am all good now.  Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try filtering the data and plot it.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df_iris <- iris
df_iris$Species[1:10] <- NA
df_iris %>% # this will show NA as a category
  ggplot(aes(x=Species, y =Sepal.Length)) + geom_boxplot()

df_iris %>%
  filter(!is.na(Species)) %>% # this will NOT show NA as a category
  ggplot(aes(x=Species, y =Sepal.Length)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Also, if it is a factor/categorical variable, check levels, for example `levels(df$var)` , and redefine the levels with `factor(..., levels = ...)` as needed.